# Random Dropzone error on Windows IIS web server

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, dropzone.js

I am encountering a very bizarre error with a dropzone that I have in my ASP.NET web application. My problem is that I am uploading entire directories worth of files (sometimes over 400 files) at a time. The uploads worked perfectly on my development machine using XAMPP, but when I transferred it to a web server using IIS, I started to notice seemingly random cases where a 500 error will occur with the dropzone. The strange thing is that the one or two files that error out are always small and they actually get uploaded to the target directory (even though there is an error). I have no problems with large files because I changed the php.ini file and configuration settings on the web server to accommodate them. The error will also not happen to the same folder all the time. Sometimes the entire folder will be free of an error and other times not. As an fyi, I thought that maybe the problem was permissions related, so I tried changing Windows folder permissions for the IIS_IUSRS user on the upload folder to no effect. I am at wits end as to the problem.  The following is my dropzone code:

```
    // Dropzone class:
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    $("#dropzone").dropzone({
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drag and drop file geodatabase here<h5>(one file geodatabase at a time; upload when complete)</h5>",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        clickable: false,
        createImageThumbnails: false,
        parallelUploads: 1000,
        maxFilesize: 500,
        previewsContainer: '#preview',
        url: dropzoneUrl,
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            myDropzone.on("processing", function (file) {
                myDropzone.options.url = dropzoneUrl + "/" + projectName + "/" + $("#database").text() + "/";
            });
            myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                if (!isDirectory) {
                    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                } else {
                    if (file.name.endsWith(".lock"))
                    {
                        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                    }
                }
            });
            myDropzone.on("drop", function (event) {
                var length = event.dataTransfer.items.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var entry = event.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
                    var path = entry.fullPath.substring(1);
                    if (entry.isFile || !path.endsWith(".gdb")) {
                        isDirectory = false;
                    } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
                        isDirectory = true;
                        myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
                        $("#database").text(path);
                        $("#error").text("");
                        $("#upload").prop("disabled", false);
                        $("#clear").prop("disabled", false);
                        $("#folder").show();
                    }
                }
            });
            myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
                if (!isError) {
                    var db = $("#database").text();
                    $("#<%= txtDatabase.ClientID %>").val(db);
                    $("#<%= txtOrigin.ClientID %>").val("-1");
                    $("#<%= btnAdd.ClientID %>").click();
                    $("#error").text("");
                } else {
                    isError = false;
                }
            });
            myDropzone.on("error", function (file, errorMessage) {
                myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
                $("#error").text("Upload error occurred!");
                $("#database").text("");
                $("#upload").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#clear").prop("disabled", true)
                $("#folder").hide();
                clearProgress();
                isError = true;
            });
            $("#clear").click(function () {
                myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
                $("#database").text("");
                $("#error").text("");
                $("#upload").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#clear").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#folder").hide();
            });
            $("#upload").click(function (e) {
                showProgress();
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Do you have detailed error information about the 500 error? or you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: I am afraid that there isn't any detailed error information about the 500 error.  I have looked at logs and am not getting any relevant information.  Now as far as failed request tracking goes, I am not sure how to configure that.  It does not appear as an option under IIS for the Default Web Site.

Comment: I have found that the 500 error happens on line 2980 of the dropzone.js file.  The code at that line deals with sending form data in the "submitRequest" function:  {
    key: "submitRequest",
    value: function submitRequest(xhr, formData, files) {
      xhr.send(formData);
    } // Called internally when processing is finished.
    // Individual callbacks have to be called in the appropriate sections.

  },

Comment: Based on what you posted, it’s difficult to troubleshoot your problem, I suggest you please open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this, microsoft engineers will help analyse the dump file and try to find the root cause.

Comment: I have found out some more information.  I finally got the Failed Request Tracking configured and working on IIS and have found out that there is an error in my PHP that I use for the dropzone.  For some reason, it is failing when it is trying to make a directory using mkdir().  I am not sure why this is happening because it should only try to make the directory once with the first file being uploaded, which it is doing.  However, it seems like it is trying to make the directory again with other files and that is causing a conflict.  Any thoughts?  I can supply more info if necessary.

Comment: Can you provide detailed messages in frt?

Comment: ModuleName:  FastCgiModule 
Data1:  FASTCGI_RESPONSE_ERROR
Data2:  PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\upload.php on line 17
ErrorCode:  Access is denied. (0x5)

ModuleName:  FastCgiModule 
Notification:  EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus:  500 
HttpReason:  Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus:  0 
ErrorCode:  The operation completed successfully. (0x0) 
ConfigExceptionInfo

Comment: It seems that IIS user does not have write permissions for the wwwroot folder. This can be solved by granting full permissions to the IIS_IUSRS user for wwwroot. 1.Open File Explorer and go to C:/inetpub/ 2.Right click on wwwroot and click on "Properties" 3.Go to the Security tab and click "Edit..." to edit permissions 4.Find and select the IIS user. In my case, it was called IIS_IUSRS ([server name]\IIS_IUSRS). 5. Select the "Allow" checkbox for all permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, that did not work.  It isn't the wwwroot folder that I am trying to write to, though.  It is D:\uploads and that folder already had full permissions granted to it for the IIS_IUSRS user.  The upload errors on a completely random basis, even though all the files for a folder are ultimately uploaded.  I just get an error return from the dropzone and an FRT written. Once I get the error I can delete the folder that errored, wait a few seconds, try again, and then everything works just fine.  There is no error with the dropzone and no FRT.

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.